# Laravel QR code scanner

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I'm interested in adding QR Scanner to my Laravel project, I found one that suits me it's called gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader there is also a written tutorial how to install it, but I just don't know where to add those codes or files. I've installed everything the problem is that I just don't know what to edit and how.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, find a professional who can implement QR code to your application. Or obviously ask the correct question, not a broad or off-topic one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response: but for anyone who comes across this like me...

gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader was created using VueJS a Javascript Framework. Since you use Laravel: VueJS already comes preinstalled with Laravel depending on the version you use. You should also have Npm in order to use the npm run watch (the watcher).

Follow the installation steps found at their GitHub and then Simply create a new VueJS component and paste the code found in GitHub: gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader: while having a little understanding you can easily integrate this with Laravel by mounting the component where you wish to have the scanner in your project and viola it should work as advertised.

I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score -4):

You should try this one laravel package:-

https://github.com/werneckbh/laravel-qr-code

It would be best for you, because there are only few steps and that are too easy.

Comment: I have QR code generator and its working, now I need qr scan.